# Переданное в БД MySQL число DOUBLE разбивается на несколько колонок

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Пытаюсь внести в БД число DOUBLE и дату в формате Date(она правильно записывается)

```java
stat.executeUpdate(String.format("INSERT INTO literDB VALUES (%f, '%s')",  result, date));
```

В таблице literDB 3 колонки

```sql
(ID INT AUTO_INCRIMENT, Result DOUBLE, Date Date)
```

result является DOUBLE, например 7,81. В БД же от него в колонку ID уходит число 7, а в колонку Result попадает 810000. В БД пробовал выставлять разные параметры типа колонки Result,но не помогает.
Неправильно запрос написан? Или в БД что-то не так? Пробовал явно указывать в какие колонки писать данные,но тогда исключение выскакивает

Comment: 1) В запросе не указаны конкретные поля, в которые следует поместить передаваемые значения. 2) Запятая разделяет значения в блоке VALUES. 3) Десятичный разделитель в числовом значении должен быть точкой, а не запятой.

Comment: *Пробовал явно указывать в какие колонки писать данные, о тогда исключение выскакивает* Указать поля - правильно. Но, с учётом вышесказанного, ещё необходимо обеспечить, чтобы значение для поля result передавалось в виде `7.81` - с точкой в качестве разделителя.

Comment: 1) Если я правильно понял,то поле с автоинкрементом можно не указывать в запросе. 2) Так вроде в VALUES параметры и должны через запятую перечисляться 3) В программе вывожу значение переменной Result, оно выводится через точку, например "5.78".В Java double хранится с точкой или с запятой?

Comment: *Если я правильно понял,то поле с автоинкрементом можно не указывать в запросе.* Не можно, а нужно. В крайнем случае для этого поля надо передавать значение NULL, а не что-то конкретное. Только тогда автоинкремент сработает. *В Java double хранится с точкой или с запятой?* Ни так ни эдак. Уж не поленитесь почитать справку о разнице между хранением и отображением хранимого.

Comment: Спасибо. Читаю изучаю. Пробовал парсить значение и локализацию менял,пока без толку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
String.format("INSERT INTO literDB VALUES (%f, '%s')",  result, date)
```

- никогда не делайте так, не используйте форматирование строк для подстановки параметров в SQL запрос. Это в лучшем случае приведет к проблемам типа конвертации чисел в строки с запятой как у вас, в худшем - к уязвимости кода к [SQL инъекции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0). Используйте [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

Чтобы значения попадали в нужные колонки, нужно после имени таблицы перечислить в скобках имена этих колонок.

```java
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO literDB (Result, Date) VALUES (?, ?)");
pstmt.setDouble(1, result);
pstmt.setDate(2, date);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: ```PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO literDB VALUES (?, ?)");```

Comment: Чуть поправил запрос, чтобы значения попадали в нужные колонки

Comment: ```PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO literDB VALUES (?, ?)");```
IDE ругается на con.prepareStatement, пытается заменить на con.getResultSet, но тогда сам запрос не выполняется

Comment: Поправил,переменную не меняет, пытается сам метод поменять. Пойду еще почитаю про PreparedStatement

Comment: Не нужно ничего менять. Сам код выполняется (если проигнорировать что IDE ругается), или ошибку выводит? Если выводит ошибку, напишите какую.

Comment: Даже не компилируется,пишет:
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method prepareStatement(java.lang.String)
  location: variable stat of type java.sql.Statement

Comment: Вы пытаетесь prepareStatement от stat вызвать? Нужно от соединения вызывать, от того же от которого вы stat создали. PreparedStatement полностью заменяет ваш stat.

Comment: @Алексей, метод `prepareStatement` нужно вызвать у объекта `Connection`, который представляет соединение с базой данных!  Вы же пытаетесь его вызвать у объекта `stat` -- `Statement`, о чём вам и сообщает ошибка.

Comment: Вы были правы, вызывал метод не у того объекта. Сейчас все заработало.